# Kinetic properties in OpenLayers 6

Tags: openlayers, ol-interaction

I'd like to know how to adjust properties of `ol/Kinetic`. And also, what are the default properties when using the default `ol/interaction/DragRotateAndZoom` ?

Properties are `decay`, `minVelocity` and `delay`. I tried to get a sense of those values by tweaking them quite randomly but nothing seems to create a panning with a nice inertia. I also tried to find answers inside the source code [here](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/v6.1.0/src/ol/Kinetic.js), but I couldn't find any.

Here's my attempt

```
var interactionPan = new ol.interaction.DragPan ({
    kinetic: new ol.Kinetic(-20, 1, 30)
});
```

Comment: The default is here https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/src/ol/interaction.js#L93

Comment: Thanks, it's working great now.